# How do I list all the queries in a MS Access file using OleDB in C#?

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

I have an Access 2003 file that contains 200 queries, and I want to print out their representation in SQL. I can use Design View to look at each query and cut and paste it to a file, but that's tedious. Also, I may have to do this again on other Access files, so I definitely want to write a program to do it.

Where are queries stored an Access db? I can't find anything saying how to get at them. I'm unfamiliar with Access, so I'd appreciate any pointers. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Procedures are what you're looking for:

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
conn.Open();

DataTable queries = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Procedures, null);

conn.Close();
```

This will give you a DataTable with the following columns in it (among others):

PROCEDURE_NAME: Name of the query

PROCEDURE_DEFINITION: SQL definition

So you can loop through the table like so:

```
foreach(DataRow row in queries.Rows)
{
    // Do what you want with the values here
    queryName = row["PROCEDURE_NAME"].ToString();
    sql = row["PROCEDURE_DEFINITION"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I only had to change one thing - use OleDBSchemaGuid.Procedures instead of .Views. 

And then the fields you want are PROCEDURE_NAME and PROCEDURE_DEFINITIONS respectively.

Comment: Glad it helped! I'll edit the actual answer so it's properly correct now.

Comment: Some corrections: The column name is PROCEDURE_DEFINITION (not plural). And to get all queries, you have to retrieve both procedures and queries. Procedures are those that take parameters.  For queries, the columns are TABLE_NAME and VIEW_DEFINITION.

Comment: s/queries/views/ on that last answer

Comment: @Mark B.  Is there a reason some of the queries wouldn't be returned.  I'm using this exact method and I'm missing some queries.

Comment: Jim, see Thomas' comment above about getting both procedures and views - hopefully that will help you out.

Answer (score 1):

you can put this together using the OleDbConnection's **GetSchema** method along with what Remou posted with regards to the ADO Schemas

**oops forgot link:  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.getschema.aspx)**

Answer (score 1):

In case you wanted to do a quick query by hand.

```
SELECT MSysObjects.Name
FROM MSysObjects
WHERE type = 5
```

Answer (score -2):

Not in C#, but may be a good place to start:

http://www.datastrat.com/Code/DocDatabase.txt