# How do I extract table names from MS Access database using ADO

Tags: c#, sql, database, ado.net

i tried using this code :

```
OleDbConnection c = new OleDbConnection(con);
string SQLS = "SELECT MSysObjects.Name FROM MSysObjects WHERE MSysObjects.Name Not Like 'MsyS*' AND MSysObjects.Type=1 ORDER BY MSysObjects.Name";
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(SQLS, c);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

But i got  this exception:

> Record(s) cannot be read; no read permission on 'MSysObjects'.

Now, i need to transfer the entire ms-access database to mysql programmaticaly, thus i need the database names. How do I work my way around this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;

public class DatabaseInfo {    
    public static void Main () { 
        String connect = "Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;data source=.\\Employee.mdb";
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connect);
        con.Open();  
        Console.WriteLine("Made the connection to the database");

        Console.WriteLine("Information for each table contains:");
        DataTable tables = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables,new object[]{null,null,null,"TABLE"});

        Console.WriteLine("The tables are:");
            foreach(DataRow row in tables.Rows) 
                Console.Write("  {0}", row[2]);


        con.Close();
    }
}
```

///taken from 
http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Database-ADO.net/Getalltablenames.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can access it like this:

```
OleDbConnection conn =
 new OleDbConnection(
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
    "C:\\phycoaide\\phycoaide.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;");

// retrieving schema for a single table
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("taxa", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect;
conn.Open();
OleDbDataReader reader =
 cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly);
DataTable schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable();
reader.Close();
conn.Close();
```

See http://harborsparrow.blogspot.com/2009/05/c-code-to-get-schema-of-access-table.html for more details.

EDIT:
Ok, so then you can retrieve all the tables using a solution like this: [How do I list all the queries in a MS Access file using OleDB in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371404/how-do-i-list-all-the-queries-in-a-ms-access-file-using-oledb-in-c) and then loop through them.

Comment: i going  with this assuming i do not know  what the table of the database are .

Comment: Glad I could help.  Please mark this as an answer if it does the trick!  :-)

Comment: but i seek  different kind of answer...:)

Comment: i assume  that i do not know the name of the tables in this database

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Kros.Utils.MsAccess](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Kros.Utils.MsAccess/). This package has support for [MsAccess database schema](https://kros-sk.github.io/Kros.Libs/api/Kros.Data.Schema.MsAccess.html).